# Comments on School "Pages"

Tags: facebook, comments, settings

I have made School Pages through Facebook for each of the schools in my district, but we would like them to be informational in nature without the ability for non-admins to comment.  Right now, I have them set so that non-admins cannot post original threads, but they can comment on a thread that has been posted.

Is there a way that we can completely remove the ability of non-admin folks to post comments of any kind?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a development question but I'll answer anyway.

No you can't remove the ability for users to comment on posts on the page.